# Get a list of records from a collection sorted by count and uniqueness of a field

Tags: mongodb

So I have a bunch of documents in a MongoDB collection and it seems that the collection is growing a little faster than we thought.

Is there a way to get a list from a collection that will count the number of documents that have X as a value in a field.

For example(I'll just make data up)

there are 4 values possible for the field (reference).

1. /content/public
2. /content/private
3. /resource/something
4. /much/wow

Is there a way to get a list from mongo that says:

- 1231 Records have /content/public as the value for reference.
- 21312312 have /content/private
- 34 have /resource/something
- 34242 have /much/wow

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the aggregation tools for this. You haven't listed a language in your question, so here's the mongodb command directly. This assumes your collection is named 'urls'.

```
db.urls.aggregate([{$group: {_id:'$reference', total:{$sum:1} } }]);
```

Comment: Would there be a way to list the amount per value of reference? I'm going to be running this in mongodb directly as this is going to be an informative query.